# Compute the number of ways a given amount (cents) can be changed

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, recursion, dynamic-programming

> Given an infinite number of different coin types (such as pennies,
>   nickels, dimes, quarters) find out how many ways n cents can be
>   represented.

My code appears to work (although I am curious to know if it has any correctness issue). But I feel like the memoization I am doing is a bit inelegant. Can we do without dictionaries/maps, perhaps a dynamic programming based approach using 2d arrays? Or is that even worse in terms of time and space complexity?

Also is my code to update the memoized_sol good in terms of coding technique?

```
'''
Parameters:
    cents: amount to get change for.
    coin_vals: list of coin denominations in no particular order.

Returns: 
    number of ways <cents> can be changes using any number of coins from the given list
'''
def get_coin_change_count (cents, coin_vals):
    memoized_sol = {}
    return compute_coin_change_count(cents, coin_vals, 0, memoized_sol )

def compute_coin_change_count (rem_cents, coin_vals, coin_index, memoized_sol ):

    if coin_index in memoized_sol:
        if rem_cents in memoized_sol[coin_index]:
            return memoized_sol[coin_index][rem_cents]
    else:
        memoized_sol[coin_index] = {}

    if rem_cents == 0:
        return 1

    if coin_index >= len(coin_vals):
        return 0

    coin_val = coin_vals[coin_index]

    i = 0
    count = 0
    while i*coin_val <= rem_cents:
        count = count + compute_coin_change_count\
            ( rem_cents - i*coin_val, coin_vals, coin_index+1, memoized_sol )
        i = i + 1

    memoized_sol[coin_index][rem_cents] = count
    return count


w = get_coin_change_count ( 37, [10, 1, 5, 25])
print (w)
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? As you may be interested in [`functools.lru_cache(None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any correctness issues, but it could be more idiomatic.

> ```
>     if coin_index in memoized_sol:
>         if rem_cents in memoized_sol[coin_index]:
>             return memoized_sol[coin_index][rem_cents]
>     else:
>         memoized_sol[coin_index] = {}
> ```

Check out first [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and then [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for ways to simplify the memoisation - although note that `lru_cache` has a subtlety in that it doesn't like `list` as an argument type.

---

> ```
>     if rem_cents == 0:
>         return 1
>
>     if coin_index >= len(coin_vals):
>         return 0
> ```

IMO these should have gone before the memoisation code, because they are non-memoised special cases. But I freely admit that this is mainly a matter of opinion. The only real difference effected would be to avoid initialising `memoized_sol[len(coin_vals)]`.

---

> ```
>     i = 0
>     count = 0
>     while i*coin_val <= rem_cents:
>         count = count + compute_coin_change_count\
>             ( rem_cents - i*coin_val, coin_vals, coin_index+1, memoized_sol )
>         i = i + 1
> ```

Using `sum` and `range` this could be simplified to

```
count = sum(compute_coin_change_count(
        surplus, coin_vals, coin_index + 1, memoized_sol)
    for surplus in range(rem_cents, -1, -coin_vals[coin_index]))
```

(I'm not quite sure what the most Pythonesque indentation would be - I wouldn't normally follow PEP8 on maximum line lengths).

---

I would also be tempted to use sublists and eliminate the need for `coin_index`, but that depends on how you're handling memoisation.

---

Putting it all together, I get

```
from functools import lru_cache


def get_coin_change_count(cents, coin_vals):
    @lru_cache(None)
    def inner(remaining, idx):
        if remaining == 0:
            return 1

        if idx == len(coin_vals):
            return 0

        return sum(inner(surplus, idx + 1)
                   for surplus in range(remaining, -1, -coin_vals[idx]))
    return inner(cents, 0)


print(get_coin_change_count(37, [10, 1, 5, 25]))
```

and here the indentation does pass PEP8, in part because of shorter names. Note that using an inner function allows memoisation with `lru_cache` and allows the short name `inner` because its scope is restricted enough that this is sufficiently expressive.